# Онлайн сервера discord в названии канала

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

Возникла такая проблема с ботов discord. Мне нужно, что бы бот выводил количество пользователей онлайн в названии канала. Имеется 2 кода. Первый Не работает вовсе. После запуска бота он показывает правильное значение, а потом это число только растет, не зависимо от реального числа пользователей онлайн.

```js
async function test1() {
    bot.channels.find(c => c.id === "ID канала").setName(`В сети: ${bot.guilds.get('ID сервера').presences.size}`);
}; setInterval(test1, 30000)
```

Второй работает и обновляет информацию корректно, но показывает только тех пользователей, у которых горит зеленый статус. Желтых и красных он не считает.

```js
async function test1() {
    bot.channels.find(c => c.id === "ID канала").setName(`В сети: ${bot.guilds.get('ID сервера').members.filter(m => ["online"].includes(m.presence.status)).size}`);
};setInterval(test1, 30000)
```

Подскажите правильный код, что бы учитывались не только пользователи со статусом "в сети", но и "не активен", "не беспокоить"

```js
const channelId = 'ID канала';
function test1() {
 const channel = bot.channels.find(channel => channel.id === channelId);
 const allMembers = bot.guilds.get('ID сервера').members;
 const notOfflineMembers = allMembers.filter(member => member.status !== 'offline');
 channel.setName(`В сети: ${notOfflineMembers.length}`);
}
test1();
setInterval(() => test1(), 30000);
```

Ругается на

```js
E:\BDOhelp\bot.js:67
        const allMembers = bot.guilds.get('674747448534630421').members;
                                                               ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'members' of undefined
    at test1 (E:\BDOhelp\bot.js:67:57)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\BDOhelp\bot.js:73:1)
```

Итоговый вариант:

```js
async function test1() {
    bot.channels.find(c => c.id === "ID канала").setName(`Участников: ${bot.guilds.get('ID сервера').members.size}`);
    bot.channels.find(c => c.id === "ID канала").setName(`В сети: ${bot.guilds.get('ID сервера').members.filter((member) => !member.user.bot && member.user.presence.status !== 'offline').size}`);
};
setInterval(test1, 30000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Подключаем библиотеку - npm install discord.js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

// Инициализируем клиент
const client = new Discord.Client();

// Подгружаем конфигурационный файл с токеном и ID сервера
const config = require('./config.json');

// Авторизуем клиент
client.login(config.token);

// Дожидаемся события ready для подлюкчения бота к серверам
client.on('ready', () => {
    setChannelName();
    setInterval(setChannelName, 30 * 1000);
});

// Асинхронная функция установки названия сервера
async function setChannelName() {
    // Находим наш сервер
    const channel = client.guilds.array().find((guild) => guild.id === config.channelID);

    // Проверяем найден ли сервер
    if (!channel) return;

    // Посылаем запрос для получения списка всех участников на сервере
    const responseMembers = await channel.fetchMembers();

    // Фильтруем коллекцию участников, не бот и не оффлайн.
    const notOfflineMembersLength = responseMembers.members.filter(
        (member) => !member.user.bot && member.user.presence.status !== 'offline'
    ).size;

    // Устанавливаем название сервера
    channel.setName(`В сети: ${notOfflineMembersLength}`);
}
```

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю с ID канала и сервера? Посмотрите мое исправление. У Вас кол-во участников ссылается на канал, а не сервер.

Comment: @MrSovik предоставьте документацию которой вы пользуетесь и ссылку на `Bot`, протестирую лично

Comment: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome
https://yadi.sk/d/7LbU6vPRdReGIw

Comment: @MrSovik обновил ответ и протестировал лично - работает.

Comment: Благодарю. Только я не пойму, куда в Вашем коде вставлять ID сервера и ID канала, который будет переименован? (Да, я очень очень начинающий в этом деле :()

Comment: @MrSovik я добавил `channelID` в `config.json` файл. `"channelID": "ID"`

Comment: Добавил в `botconfig.json` строку `"channelID":"718144572525510716"`. Все равно не работает :( Ему же нужно еще id сервера, на котором канал создан?

Comment: @MrSovik я и вставил туда только ID сервера. Не ID канала, а именно самого сервера и всё работает.

Comment: А какой канал тогда он у Вас переименовывает?

Comment: Вы, наверное, немного недопоняли меня. Посмотрите второй мой код который в вопросе. Он рабочий. Там указан ID сервера и ID канала. ID сервера он статичен, а каналов много и у каждого свой ID. И нужно указать ID канала (комнаты), имя которого будет меняться.

Comment: В принципе... Взял Ваш фильтр и вставил в свой второй код. Получилось так:
Нужно понаблюдать, но вроде бы работает в таком виде

Comment: @MrSovik завтра переделаю под все под каналы на сервере. Сегодня поздно уже

Comment: А мой итоговый код Вам не нравится? Вроде работает. Мой код + Ваш фильтр.

Comment: Хм. Спустя пару дней нормальной работы, бот опять начинает глючить. Завышает реальное число людей онлайн. Вы говорили переделаете Ваш вариант под каналы. Актуально еще? Может быть Ваш вариант заработает нормально...